# Function as an argument of predicate

Tags: functions, predicate-logic

If we have predicate $P_1(x,y)$

[image: Predicate]

and two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x)$

[image: Two functions]

what will be this predicate? 
Could you explain me a general principle of substitution functions in predicates?

[image: Second predicate]

Comment: I'm not sure about the question, since filling in $(a,a)$ will give $1$, but $(c,c)$ will give $0$. If you're asking for another table then I really guess you can do that yourself!

Comment: I think your $g$ table is not formatted quite correctly. Can you explain what are $g(a),g(b),g(c)$?

Comment: @Ian *g* table means that *g(x)* equals first column of *g* and *g(y)* equals second column of *g*.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's formatted differently because $g$ is unary and $f$ is binary. OK.

Comment: Well, then you just work out the table one step at a time. For example, calling your predicate $P_2(x,y)$ we have $P_2(a,a)=P_1(f(a,g(a)),a)=P_1(f(a,c),a)=P_1(a,a)=1$. Do it again with the other 8 pairs.

Comment: @Ian Hmmm... Thanks so much!